# Python27 - on windows 8.1 or 10 not showing the printers

Tags: python, windows, winapi, printing

I have 32-bit Python and win32print of 32bit installed. When i execute the following code on windows 8 or 10 i do not get any printers output list. only its printing: `()`

[image]

Why its not working?

```
import win32print
printers = win32print.EnumPrinters(5)
print printers
```

**Expected output:**

[image]

Try 1: When i tried this code, the printer wake up but nothing gets printed no papers gets out, no printing happens at all.

```
import os, sys
import win32print
p = win32print.OpenPrinter('RICOH Aficio SP 4310N') 
job = win32print.StartDocPrinter (p, 1, ("test of raw data", None, "RAW")) 
win32print.StartPagePrinter (p) 
win32print.WritePrinter (p, "data to print") 
win32print.EndPagePrinter (p)
```

Try 2: this is printing to the printer with A4 paper

[image]

```
import win32ui
X=50; Y=50
input_string = "COPY PASTE COPY PASTE COPY PASTE LINE"
multi_line_string = input_string.split()
hDC = win32ui.CreateDC ()
hDC.CreatePrinterDC ('RICOH Aficio SP 4310N')
hDC.StartDoc ('FILE NAME FILE NAME')
hDC.StartPage ()
for line in multi_line_string:
     hDC.TextOut(X,Y,line)
     Y += 100
hDC.EndPage ()
hDC.EndDoc ()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following

```
printers = win32print.EnumPrinters(win32print.PRINTER_ENUM_LOCAL, None, 1)
print (printers)
```

In Windows 8 and 10 `"Microsoft Print to PDF"` should be listed. And you can use

```
hDC.CreatePrinterDC ('Microsoft Print to PDF')
```

See also documentation for [(EnumPrinters/Python)](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32print__EnumPrinters_meth.html) and [(EnumPrinters/WinAPI)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162692(v=vs.85).aspx)

---

Example, this code will print PDF file directly to `"c:\\test\\_python.pdf"`. If `StartDoc` does not include file name then print dialog box will ask for pdf output file name.

```
import win32print, win32ui

X=50; Y=50
input_string = "COPY PASTE COPY PASTE COPY PASTE LINE"
multi_line_string = input_string.split()
hDC = win32ui.CreateDC ()
hDC.CreatePrinterDC ('Microsoft Print to PDF')
hDC.StartDoc('PrintJobName','c:\\test\\_python.pdf')
hDC.StartPage ()
for line in multi_line_string:
     hDC.TextOut(X,Y,line)
     Y += 100
hDC.EndPage ()
hDC.EndDoc ()
```

Comment: I revisited this answer by accident, it seems you just had the wrong parameter for `EnumPrinters`. My previous answer doesn't make any sense, I don't know what I was going on about. I updated it. Maybe I will delete the old answer.